# Firestore - cursors in paginated queries (problem when docs are deleted)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I have a problem with my app in paginated flatlists...

Currently, I am sorting data by date, and using the doc ref as cursor. But, what will happen if this referenced document is deleted before starting the next query? It seems that the pagination will be broken, starting fetching again from the start (not really sure).

Also, previosly, I was using the date field of the documents as cursors... but, what about if 2 documents have the same date? Will the pagination cause repeated results in some cases?

Any ideas?

Comment: There are two questions here. Please limit yourself to one question per post. Also note that both of these can be fairly easily tested, so I recommend giving it a try yourself - and then possibly self-answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also, previosly, I was using the date field of the documents as cursors... but, what about if 2 documents have the same date? Will the pagination cause repeated results in some cases?

You can pass multiple values into the `startAt`, `startAfter`, `endAt` and `endAfter` methods, precisely to ensure this doesn't become a problem. If you only pass in a date value, the database has no other option than to start/end returning documents at/after/before that date value. But if you pass in the date **and the ID** of the anchor document, it can always clip the results exactly at/after/before that document.

Note that this is automatically handled for you when you pass in a `DocumentSnapshot`, which is why I typically prefer that over passing in individual values.